# How to to suppress error in bash script

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression

I am trying to suppress error generated by date command but still error is coming post executing script.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

input="30 FEB 2022"
reg="^[0-9]{1,2}\s[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\s[0-9]{1,4}$"

if [[ $input =~ $reg ]]
then
        echo "VALID Date Format : $input"
        #output=$(`date -d "$input" +"%d-%b-%Y, %A"` 2>&1 > /dev/null)
        output=`date -d "$input" +"%d-%b-%Y, %A"` 2>&1 > /dev/null
else
        echo "INVALID Date Format : $input"
        output="-1"
fi

echo $output
```

After execution Output -

```
root@ip-xx-x-xx-xxx:~# ./exDate.sh 
VALID Date Format : 30 FEB 2022
date: invalid date '30 FEB 2022'
```

Please advise how can i suppress error?

Answer (score 8):

You have already gotten answers giving you better approaches, so I will just answer the question you asked. The reason you are still seeing the error message is because the order of redirection matters. Redirections are read from left to right, so `2>&1 > /dev/null` means "first redirect stderr to stdout and *then* redirect stdout to `/dev/null`". This means that your errors are getting printed to stdout and the normal stdout is being redirected to `/dev/null`. You can see this by piping stdout to `wc`:

```
## No redirection
$ date -d foo 
date: invalid date ‘foo’

## Nothing is printed to stdout, the error goes to stderr
## and wc has nothing to count
$ date -d foo | wc
date: invalid date ‘foo’
      0       0       0

## Redirect using 2>&1 > /dev/null
$ date -d foo 2>&1 > /dev/null
date: invalid date ‘foo’

## The error is now being printed to stdout, wc counts it
$ date -d foo 2>&1 > /dev/null | wc
      1       4      29
```

What you want is to redirect stdout to `/dev/null` first and *then* redirect stderr to stdout: `> /dev/null 2>&1`. This behaves as you want:

```
$ date -d foo  > /dev/null 2>&1 
$
```

Comment: since they're using `date` inside a command substitution, they also need to move the redirection there. and also _not_ redirect stdout, since it's needed for capturing the output. `output=$(date -d foo 2>/dev/null)` should work in that context.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot validate a date with a regular expression or pattern. (Well, I suppose you might be able to do so, but it would be unpleasant.)

Instead, use the `date` command itself to validate the input. Write this script to the file `exDate` and make it executable (`chmod a+x exDate`):

```
#!/bin/bash

input=$1
if date --date "$input" >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    # Good date
    output=$(date --date "$input" +'%d-%b-%Y, %A')
else
    # Date parsing failed
    printf 'INVALID Date Format : %s\n' "$input" >&2
    output='-1'
fi

printf "%s\n" "$output"
```

Example run

```
./exDate '30 FEB 2022'
INVALID Date Format : 30 FEB 2022
-1

./exDate '24 FEB 2022'
24-Feb-2022, Thursday

./exDate '2022-04-13'
13-Apr-2022, Wednesday
```

If the last option is unacceptable (i.e. you want to accept dates only in the form `d(d) MMM yyyy`) then you would need to pattern match as well as using `date` to validate:

```
if [[ "$input" =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}\ [a-zA-Z]{3}\ [0-9]{4}$ ]] && date…
then
```

You can merge the `if date...` with the `output=` assignment, simplifying the code by then needing only to handle the failure case:

```
if ! output=$(date --date "$input" +'%d-%b-%Y, %A' 2>/dev/null)
then
    # Date parsing failed
    printf 'INVALID Date Format : %s\n' "$input" >&2
    output='-1'
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

The default input date format is USA. The month has to be before the day.

```
$ date -d '02/02/2022'
Wed 02 Feb 2022 12:00:00 AM UTC

$ date -d '02/22/2022'
Wed 22 Feb 2022 12:00:00 AM UTC
```

Yes, the month could be given in letters (FEB or feb, even if the locale is in another country)

```
$ date -d 'FEB 22 2022'
Tue 22 feb 2022 00:00:00 UTC

$ ( LC_ALL=es_ES.utf8 date -d 'FEB 22 2022')
mar 22 feb 2022 00:00:00 UTC

$ ( LC_ALL=ja_JP.utf8 date -d 'FEB 22 2022')
2022年  2月 22日 火曜日 00:00:00 UTC
```

But, there is no way that any date will **not** try to report an error if the given date **does not exist**. A 30 of February doesn't exist. There is no output from date in such case. And, it sets its exit state to 1. We can actually use that to validate the input date without needing the regex:

```
#!/bin/bash

input="${1:-"30 FEB 2022"}"

if     output=`date -d "$input" +"%d-%b-%Y, %A" 2>&1`
then   echo "VALID   Date : $input"        
else   echo "INVALID Date : $input"
       output="-1"
fi

printf '%s\n' "$output"
```

Of course, the redirections must be inside the *`` `...` ``* for them to work.

```
$ ./exDate.sh
INVALID Date : 30 FEB 2022
-1

$ ./exDate.sh "22 FEB 2022"
INVALID Date : 22 FEB 2022
-1

$ ./exDate.sh "FEB 22 2022"
VALID   Date : FEB 22 2022
22-Feb-2022, Tuesday

$ ./exDate.sh "FEB 30 2022"
INVALID Date : FEB 30 2022
```